# How to retrieve all topics from Azure Bus Service?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I have a Azure service bus containing 12 Topics. I am making a scale-able application where **if the number of topics isreduced or increased**, the application should use `connectionString` to get all topics names for that service bus.

How can I get all topics name from a particular Azure service bus?

Please provide code sample that retrieve topic list from a particular Azure service bus.

Comment: namespaceManager.GetTopics()?

Comment: @RyanChu Please put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks @RyanChu for correct answer.

Here is the required code segment that implements above requirement ,

```
string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
NamespaceManager nm = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
IEnumerable<TopicDescription> topicList=nm.GetTopics();
        foreach(var td in topicList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(td.Path);
        }
```

For more details , refer [NamespaceManager.GetTopics() Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835125.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft.Azure.Servicebus is a package for .NET Core. The syntax is slightly different.
This is a piece of code in my project.

```
var managementClient = new ManagementClient(_connectionString);
var topicDescriptions = new List<TopicDescription>();

for (int skip = 0; skip < 1000; skip += 100)
{
    var topics = await managementClient.GetTopicsAsync(100, skip);
    if (!topics.Any()) break;

    topicDescriptions.AddRange(topics);
}
```